# Open hyperlink in new tab and run a php function

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have a countdown timer in javascript and when it gets to the end I'd like to be able to display a hyperlink or button that **opens the url in a new tab** and at the same time call a php function (which would in turn update a piece of user metadata).

I am able to do one or the other but not both at the same time.

Below is everything I've tried so far.

Please can someone help?

FYI my site is a wordpress.org site and I have all the code below within the functions.php file.

This code will open the hyperlink in a new tab but will not call the function updateUserEndSession:

```
\\
\\ bla bla javascript countdown code...
\\
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/media/imagex.jpg" target="_blank">End</a>';

 }
        }, 1000);
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>


    <?php

}

if(isset($_POST['End_sesh'])){
        updateUserEndSession();
}


function updateUserEndSession(){
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'insessionbool', False );       
}
```

This code will call the function updateUserEndSession via a button click but will not open any hyperlink:

```
\\
\\ bla bla javascript countdown code...
\\
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<form method="post" ><input type="submit" value="End" name="End_sesh"/></form>';

 }
        }, 1000);
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>


    <?php

}

if(isset($_POST['End_sesh'])){
        updateUserEndSession();
}


function updateUserEndSession(){
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'insessionbool', False );       
}
```

This code is my current best attempt to do both. It opens the hyperlink in a new tab but still does not call my function unfortunately:

```
\\
\\ bla bla javascript countdown code...
\\
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<form method="post" action="https://www.mywebsite.com/media/imagex.jpg"  target="_blank"><input type="submit" value="End" name="End_sesh"/></form>';

 }
        }, 1000);
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>


    <?php

}


if(isset($_POST['End_sesh']))
    {
        updateUserEndSession();
    }


function updateUserEndSession(){
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'insessionbool', False );       
}
```

Comment: I think that what you want to achieve can be done through asynchronous request to server. Look up XMLHttpRequest and AJAX.

Comment: Can you check what all variables are you getting in `print_r($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

Check what do you get in

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Another options is to use GET

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/?call=endUser" target="_blank">End</a>';
```

and in PHP handle like this

```
if(isset($_GET['call']) && $_GET['call'] == 'endUser')
{
    updateUserEndSession();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added ```print_r($_POST);``` to just before updateUserEndSession() is called but nothing happened. I guess because it's not going there for some reason which is the main problem? Let me try the GET method next and revert in a few.

Comment: If I try the GET method you suggested I get taken to a 404 Not Found page (because the URL "https://www.mywebsite.com/?call=endUser" is not working because of the ?call=endUser on the end). And the function also still isn't called anyway.

Comment: Just to clarify one thing. The URL I am trying to send user to is an image. I have edited my question to reflect this. Thus GET method is not working because essentially www.mywebsite,com/media/imagex.jpg/?call=endUser doesn't exist

Comment: If I try e.g. "www.mywebsite,com/?call=endUser/media/imagex.jpg" then the function is triggered so that's good but the new tab that opens up is of the home page not the image page that I want to go to.